# Browse brush to be linked 2.8 shortcut?

Tags: texture-painting

there's something I try to adopt 2.8 shortcut instead of 2.79 ones, but some shortcut did not implement in 2.8. like I can't find scroll 1~0 to indicated the paintbrush on 2.8. Does anybody find its shortcut or any way to assign it?

Comment: 2.8 separates the brushes into Tools and then into palettes of similar brush tools. The design docs online from William indicate that there will be a way to create a master palette of brushes to pull from as a way of organizing your brushes, but the work hasn't been completed yet to enable faster brush picking. I haven't found a way yet aside from python to set shortcuts to the brushes, and have just been using the properties editor open on the side as a way to browse the subtools inside each tool.

Comment: Sometimes I'd like to switches from custom_brush_A to custom_brush_B, in 2.7, I could press 1 to 0 to easily changing. If 2.8 also make it easy would be better.